# is dva required to use antd react components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, antd

i just came across the [antd library](https://ant.design/docs/react/introduce) of react components, and the components look pretty sweet, but i am unclear if their use requires use of the redux-centric [dva framework](https://github.com/dvajs/dva).

i use redux, but would like the flexibility of not having to couple with dva just yet (although it might be sweet too)...

can anyone with experience comment around this?

thanks!

Comment: Read the docs, there are instructions for using it with Create React App as well, for example. You can use it with whatever Babel/Webpack scaffolding you like.

Comment: thanks @JesperWe. my question was really around dva as a redux strategy, not the build-scaffolding, but i gather you have enough experience to answer that question as well. i did spot a few examples which did not seem to use dva, so i guess the answer to my question is "no, dva is not required to use antd react components"...?

Comment: It's not required. I use it and I don't even know what's dva.

Comment: antd has no special relationship at all to Redux, they are two independent components. antd does not require Redux. antd does not require dva. antd does require Babel, and will benefit from the `babel-plugin-import` if you want to load in a non-monolithic fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using both `dva` and `antd` in my projects. the relationship between `antd` and `dva` is similar to the relationship between `react` and `redux`, as `antd` is a react UI components library, focusing on reusable view components, whereas `dva` is basically a lightweight wrapper of `redux` and `saga`.

`dva` is not required to use `antd`.